# Styling an individual prop that is within a paragraph of text?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to style individual props within a paragraph, however I need to style them within makeText as I am using this fulltext to be a default value for a textarea, so I can't style it down there. I'm simply aiming for to make the props. values in bold

```
makeText = (props) => {

    let fulltext = "Hi " + props.name +
        ", \nI'd like to give you improvements regarding" + 
        props.lesson +
        " you participated in " + props.course + " " + props.year + " class."

    return fulltext;
}
```

Comment: You can not have any bold text in `<textarea>` so what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a JSX instead of a string, like in the following example:

```
makeText = (props) => {

    let fulltext = <>Hi </b>{props.name}</b></>

    return fulltext;
}
```

**Note**, by the way, that you are not able to have a bold text in a text area.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the JSX from the function as below

```
makeText = (props) => {
  return <>Hi <strong>{props.name}</strong> ...</>
}
```

If the function is running in server and you're just getting the string you may return the HTML like below.

```
makeText = (props) => {
  return `Hi <strong>${props.name}</strong> .....`
}
```

And rather just using it directly try to use below code for setting the inner HTML

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: makeText()}} />;`

You're set now. You can see the text that you need in bold. You can actually insert whatever the HTML code that you want.